# TypeScript type for any string other than a specific string literal

Tags: typescript

Is it possible creating a type for any string other than a specific string literal?

`type FooString = 'foo' | string`

`type Foo = 'foo'`

`type NotFoo = ?`

Goal:

`const a: NotFoo = 'foo'; // error`

`const b: NotFoo = 'bar'; // ok`

Answer (score 5):

Conditional type will make a trick:

```js
type FooString = 'foo' | string

type Foo = 'foo'
type NotFoo<T extends string> = T extends 'foo' ? never : T

const notFoo = <T extends string>(arg: NotFoo<T>):T => arg

const result = notFoo('hello') // ok
const result2 = notFoo('foo') // error

type Result = NotFoo<'foo'> // never
type Result2 = NotFoo<'bar'> // 'bar'
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAysATgSwHYHMoF4oDkAZggVAD5QDOqmWAsAFBOiSwJ6ElwEvjQA5OMHhwAPABUoEAB7AIGACZVqtbAD5OU2fKUripKAH4oGCADcIKKAC4oEpkwDGcDDVPDRnSdLkLlqugaABQAhihYdkIiCJLqAJQ2Uria4QzMjC5uwFAoEFQArgA2OfgYngjBBAAWEEVFPPHOru55hSUATJzlMXBV3ARNGazQAEr5xaVQ0aJiBjyaAPSLphZWfGzj7cBd%20DOxBABG4QRLK0cnQA)

If `arg` is `foo`, `NotFoo` util will return `never` type.
`never` type is not something you can provide as an argument.

Comment: As an explanation: there is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to "all strings except this one" because there [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) never made it into the language... so `string & not "foo"` is not available.  Instead you can abandon specific types and opt for *constraints* like making sure that `T` is assignable to `NotFoo<T>`.  Keep in mind that without negated types, you can fool the compiler with things like `notFoo("fo"+"o")`.  You could change the constraint to disallow `string`  itself, which would be even more annoying to use.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the comment! Appreciate that!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a nice trick but not very useful. I'm trying to force any string other than "foo" and I can't force anyone to wrap his string with the notFoo() function.

Comment: @Bishok you can’t force anyone to annotate a string as `NotFoo` either, if such a type existed.  Presumably you have a function that should only *accept* a `NotFoo`, and this could be altered to accept `NotFoo<T>` for an inferred `T`. If this answer doesn’t work for you could you show exactly how it does not, with a [mcve]?