# How to make TypeScript distinguish between a template literal string and any other string?

Tags: typescript

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

I have a function that takes a second argument which is *only* required when the first argument is a string matching a template literal string. However, it appears that even when TypeScript *knows* that the first argument is such a string, it still matches the overload that takes a regular string:

```
type KnownString = `known${string}`;
type AnyString = string;

function doSomethingWithString(arg1: KnownString, onlyRequiredForKnownString: boolean): string;
function doSomethingWithString(arg1: AnyString, onlyRequiredForKnownString?: boolean): string;
function doSomethingWithString(arg1: KnownString | AnyString, onlyRequiredForKnownString?: boolean): string {
    return "The second argument is only required when `arg1` is a KnownString";
}

const thisIsAKnownString = "knownstring" as KnownString;

// @ts-expect-error Since TS knows that arg1 is a KnownString, it should require the second parameter:
doSomethingWithString(thisIsAKnownString);
```

This makes sense of course, since it *is* a regular string. Is there a way to tell that overload to match any regular string *except* `KnownString`?

(I [did try with a conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gdgewO5wMrAE4Es4HMoC8UABgNaIoAkA3gM6Y64C+xA3AFCiRQCCcI6bHgA8AFSgQAHsAhwAJrSj0h+IssYA+QlHFSZ8xfGRoGeKAH4ocCADcIGKAC4lp3B3YAzAK5wAxsCwEOCg5BFQEAFsIYAALRgB1LFjBRgAKAEMMXABGZyMUFLwAGigggBsQACUIAEcvLAwIOQAxBAx8kxVnACMEBDKIdLgASmd1PA5vPwCgkLDI6Li8ROTXDKzc3n5C3BLyqtr6xpa2jp3zHr6BodGXFUmff0Dg0PCo2ISkmJ31nLyKTqMKAAHy2AlcezgFWqdQaTVa7QB50u-UGIzGrig1HYUFxUEawC8GGCACJRDFoLQIL4gnIoJlcF4onBgFAsIp9vjDnC6UgKcFiAzssQ2Yp0rAka4SRwmOx2DS4PQoB9aABJWg8M6Yogk8jGca4En0wyS+5ygD05qgAAFgLQALRSSD+R0YDBtKCoHC+aCiVBQPVIRSxdKsoWi+kS4w7EpJJQxBBeMp0xqwxrKilKam0qBgTLpd72RzsV4LD7LL4-FXqzWmxjDDhAA) like suggested in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354585/typescript-type-for-any-string-other-than-a-specific-string-literal), but that does not appear to work with template literal strings.)

Comment: Isn't it possible for your function to receive a "known" string via the second overload anyway? I don't mean at compile-time, I mean at runtime the function still has to be able to handle such a string when the second argument is omitted. Does it throw an error in that case?

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, in my actual code there's also a runtime check in case it's called by developers who aren't using TypeScript, but I'd like for TypeScript developers to be notified of the potential error without having to trigger this code path in a running application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you dont need to overload your function.

Consider next example:

```js
type IsKnown<T extends string> = T extends `known${string}` ? true:false

type Validator<T extends boolean> = 
  T extends true 
  ? [] 
  : [boolean];

function validation<Str extends string>(arg1: Str, ...validation: [...Validator<IsKnown<Str>>]): string {
    return "The second argument is only required when `arg1` is a KnownString";
}

const knownstring = "knownstring";

validation(knownstring); // does not require second argument
validation('unknown'); // requires second argument
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgaQHYHsDuSA8AVKEAewESAJnFHMAE4CWSA5gHxQC8UuBRp5ABgNaoMAEgDelWgwC%20PKAH4o1AK4QAXADMAhgBs4EAFB7QkKADVtNEhuAoqOPIWJkoAIxQotEDUmZs9UdvZcTkrQfnJQANoAulBhKpGu7p5IUQDcBmqKSADGwDQoSFAAbuaWeQWYAMrUgY7k4nRMABQaVPQAjPHVVAA0UAB0gyVaFlb5SPERg-1mI2U2mPDI6FjdjIxRAJTxDQxQImH%20VBDAilSFAETYABbQutkFJFCt9IoAtsTAUDTkBVogUGOAEdFDRjk80LdCjwXu0ZD9nlBlhhuo0LulJAYHkhKFABCtdvRWFALviMIT0QZhqNykgmmScdRGptUlAAPRsqAkFAQcioL7A0HHCgQbFPF7vT56allcZNADkWQZ8pZ7M5grBvJFYuebUlSGABiAA)

Please keep in mind, that `function foo(a:number,...args:[]){}` evaluates to `function foo(a:number){}`

MOre information about this approach you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/validators)

Take into account, that you can compose your validators:

```js
type IsKnown<T> = T extends `known${string}` ? true : false

type StringNumber<T> = T extends `${number}` ? true : false


type Validator<T extends boolean> =
  T extends true
  ? []
  : [boolean];


function validation<Str extends string>(arg1: Str, ...validation: Validator<StringNumber<Str>> | Validator<IsKnown<Str>>): string {
  return "The second argument is only required when `arg1` is a KnownString";
}

const knownstring = "knownstring";

validation(knownstring); // does not require second argument
validation('2234'); // does not require second argument, because it is number
validation('wer'); //  requires second argument, because it is number
```

Comment: Hmm, that is certainly an interesting approach. Let me see what happens when I try that in my actual codebase.

Comment: Amazing. I'm not a big fan of the complex types that are somewhat inscrutable (especially since I'm working on a library), but it does _work_. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I tried to split type validation into several smaller type utils, so I hope it readable

Answer (score 0):

I did find another solution with function overloads and somewhat more straightforward types:

```
type KnownString = `known${string}`;
type AnyString = string;
type NotKnown<T extends AnyString> = T extends KnownString ? never : T;

function doSomethingWithString(arg1: KnownString, onlyRequiredForKnownString: boolean): string;
function doSomethingWithString<T extends AnyString>(arg1: T & NotKnown<T>): string;
function doSomethingWithString(arg1: KnownString | AnyString, onlyRequiredForKnownString?: boolean): string {
    return "The second argument is only required when `arg1` is a KnownString";
}

const thisIsAKnownString = "knownstring" as KnownString;

// @ts-expect-error Since TS knows that arg1 is a KnownString, it should require the second parameter:
doSomethingWithString(thisIsAKnownString);
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-utAVtgaCdfrDbbGFMOEA)